# recognize element content and modify dynamically using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm injecting text into page using jquery like this

```
$("#myDiv").text(someWebServiceResponse.Data);
```

this returned data is in most cases numbers divided with commas but in some cases can be 
  string as a title which is followed with numbers

Returned data case without title

```
1,2,3,4,89,11
```

Returned data case with title

```
MyTitle 1,2,3,4,89,11
```

Returned data case with title

```
MyTitle2 1,2,35,4,89,14
```

Those title and number values are dynamic ofcourse.

How can I recognize if returned data contains title (maybe using `typeofstring`) and 
 modify this returned string with title + 
 and than numbers in next line

Comment: Use `isNaN` = is not a number

Answer (score 1):

Given that the numbers are divided only by `,` and not by space, you can easily test if the string contains empty space.

Like this

```
function containsTitle(input) {
    return input.indexOf(' ') > 0;
}

...
if (containsTitle(someWebServiceResponse.Data)) {
   //TODO: split for 2 lines or whatever you need
}
```

Answer (score 1):

With your quoted examples, just find the last space if any and insert the plus sign:

```
var lastSpace = yourString.lastIndexOf(' ');
if (lastSpace != -1) {
    yourString = yourString.substring(0, lastSpace) + " +" + yourString.substring(lastSpace);
}
```

**Live Example:**

```js
test("1,2,3,4,89,11");
test("MyTitle 1,2,3,4,89,11");
test("MyTitle2 1,2,35,4,89,14");

function test(yourString) {
  var lastSpace = yourString.lastIndexOf(' ');
  if (lastSpace != -1) {
    yourString = yourString.substring(0, lastSpace) + " +" + yourString.substring(lastSpace);
  }
  snippet.log(yourString);
}
```

```html
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:-

```
var isTitle=function(txt){
  var first=txt.substr(0,txt.indexOf(',')); 
  return !$.isNumeric(first);
}
 //here how to use
alert(isTitle('1,2,3,4,89,11'));
alert(isTitle('MyTitle 1,2,3,4,89,11'));
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/guzzjty1/29/)